Problem installing Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools : Retry dowmloading and DependencyLoop
I want to install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools so I do :
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools -ProviderName nuget -Force -v

And I log this error :
VERBOSE: Suppressed Warning Unknown category for 'NuGet'::'GetDynamicOptions': 'Provider'
VERBOSE: Using the provider 'NuGet' for searching packages.
VERBOSE: Retry downloading 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-gz-semver2/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools/1.0.json' for '0' more times
VERBOSE: Retry downloading 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-gz-semver2/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools/1.1.json' for '0' more times
VERBOSE: Retry downloading 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-gz-semver2/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools/2.0.json' for '0' more times
VERBOSE: Retry downloading 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-gz-semver2/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools/2.1.json' for '0' more times
VERBOSE: Retry downloading 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-gz-semver2/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools/2.2.json' for '0' more times
VERBOSE: Retry downloading 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-gz-semver2/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools/3.0.json' for '0' more times
VERBOSE: Retry downloading 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-gz-semver2/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools/3.1.json' for '0' more times
VERBOSE: Retry downloading 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-gz-semver2/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools/5.0.json' for '0' more times
... (Same line for other pacakage)
VERBOSE: Retry downloading 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-gz-semver2/system.valuetuple/4.5.json' for '0' more times
Install-Package : Dependency loop detected for package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools -ProviderName nug ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : Deadlock detected: (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools:String) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DependencyLoopDetected,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage

I don't know why he is looking for this URL each time and did't found anything...
And at the end the error is weird as it is a microsoft package very used.
Does some one have any idea why I have this bug and how i could solve it ?
UPDATE : With a selected version, is still the same problem. It looks like it is due to the URL. For exemple https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-gz-semver2/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.design/5.0.json
return
<Error>
<Code>BlobNotFound</Code>
<Message>The specified blob does not exist. RequestId:78162bad-001e-0070-70cb-4f0400000000 Time:2024-12-16T15:02:20.7462256Z</Message>
</Error>

Thanks,
Eliott

Have you tried providing the explicit Version? So something along this: Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools -Version 8.0.0
Please make sure that you use the correct version. Latest stable is 9.0.0
I think the reason is that its downloading such old versions that it goes into the deadlock because most of it is deprecated

I tried it but it is not better
